# VB.net regex find value between second commas

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to use Regex to pull the value from between the second set of commas. That has the letter S in the in beginning word.

```
(?<=S,[^,],)[^,]+(?=,)
```

Above is the closest I can get.  It will give the value I am looking for on the BS and CS lines.  I was thinking the [^'] in the look behind would get(exclude) all the characters between the first set of commas.

```
BB,21,1.750000,0.000000,
AS,21.5,3.250000,-0.187500
BS,21,3.250000,-0.187500
CS, ,1.750000,-0.375000
DS,1,30.375000,-0.375000
QA,aa,30.375000,-0.375000
```

Looking for more than just the answer would really like an explanation so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the character class in the lookbehind at the beginning, but in this case "value from between the second set of commas" is literally 2 comma's to the left of the current value that you are matching.

The S is the last value before the comma, and it can have multiple matches as there are no anchors.

```
(?<=S,[^,]*,)[^,]+(?=,)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZgPSH/1)

If the lines start with only uppercase chars A-Z, you could match at least a single S char in that first part

```
(?<=^[A-RT-Z]*S[A-Z]*,[^,\n]*,)[^,\n]+(?=,)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `^` Start of string
  - `[A-RT-Z]*` Match optional chars A-Z without S
  - `S[A-Z]*`Match S and optional chars A-Z
  - `,[^,\n]*,` Match 2 times a comma
- `)` Close the lookbehing
- `[^,\n]+` Match 1+ chars other than a comma or newline
- `(?=,)` Assert a comma to the right

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/aHe7A8/1)

Comment: Thank you.  was having issue with testing using regex101.  I thought I need to us the * but the regex101 was giving an error "* A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width"  Your link to regex101 works but trying the example you provided in the version I have does not.  Not sure why

Comment: @user3786542 vb.net uses the .NET engine that you have to select under flavor on regex101.